# BaseAdapter not keep my update as it

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have a `ListView` with `BaseAdapter`. The row of the list contains a `TextView` and `ImageView` that implements `onClickListener`. 
My problem is  that when I press the `ImageView` it changes its background and when I press the list Item to open slide layer and close it I found that the `ImageView` changed the background to the old one.

This is the code of Adapter [TipsAdapter.java](http://www.dt-works.com/emy/TipsAdapter.java)

The Code of listView [TipsFragment](http://www.dt-works.com/emy/TipsFragment.java)

The Code of MainActivity that holds the Fragments [MainActivity.java](http://www.dt-works.com/emy/MainActivity.java)

[image]

Comment: You have to save state of your starts, create a HashMap and mark the ones checked.

Comment: could you please tell me how by source code.

Comment: Actually it seems like you are saving it's state in this code `db.addOrRemoveFavorites(tipID, isFavorite);` am I right? Are you saving it to database after they click? Plus, are you restarting your `Loader` after you came back to page? Can you show full code of your Activity/Fragment

Comment: yes, when I click button it saves it in the database, but there are a problem in retrieve when I press the item of the list.

Comment: If you can post the Activity/Fragment code that would be better. It seems like your `Cursor` is not refreshing. Or you can email me all project that would be faster solution.

Comment: Ok I'll post the whole Activity/Fragment

Comment: Look to the Update, hope it is best

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45219/discussion-between-gokhan-arik-and-eman87)